# Integrating Freeform with two CRMs?

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

We have landing pages on our site, and we want to be able to export this form data into two separate CRMs: Leads360 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The forms are using FreeForm (the remote dev team chose this.) Both of these CRMs require the form data to be submitted to a custom POST URL.

Is this possible with Freeform? I can't find anything on the Solspace site in the Freeform documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used the post submit hook in Freeform to write our own extension that submits the data to SalesForce. In this case, we use cURL to simulate a post to SalesForce's Web2Lead form rather than work with the API.

If you start in that context - An extension using the post submit hook - You can write any number of functions in there. You could submit to 1, 2, 5, 10 different services with the data that was just posted.

**Updated:** Another option, if you don't want to go the Extension route:

You can enable PHP in a template and set that template to be the Redirect URL of your Freeform form. Write out all the PHP that integrates with those CRMs in that template. There should be a way to get the Insert ID of the new Freeform entry onto the redirect URL. Within that PHP template, you can redirect the user to any other page on the site you wish.

Either way, it's a file with the PHP that does the behind the scenes POSTs to those sites. The extension is the right way to do it.

Comment: So it sounds like something that's doable, but only by writing an extension to Freeform, correct?

Comment: Don't let the "writing an extension" aspect deter you. Our SalesForce extension is a single PHP file with 150 lines of well-spaced code and comments, installed like any EE extension. It's just a few PHP functions, and a bunch of variables to store the SalesForce URLs & variables. We also have it configured to only match on Freeform forms with a certain name, rather than all forms. Jack McDade built it for us if you'd like a connection.

Comment: I would like another connection, yes, thank you very much! I personally am not at the space yet where I can build extensions, but I've installed and used them - sometimes those are the best option to do what you want to do. We just want to know what's possible when, rather than always going for a customizable solution. I did want to be able to tell my boss what can and cannot be done with Freeform, so...lots of questions. Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to contact Jack McDade (https://twitter.com/jackmcdade). Mention the Clearbold SalesForce extension.